# What the recomended way to search in concatenated columns?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
class Person
{
   string FirstName;
   string MiddleName;
   string LastName;
}
```

Lets say I have this sample data:

```
William Henry  Gates
Steven  Paul   Jobs 
Mark    Elliot Zuckerberg
```

Then, in Entity Framework/Linq I can do searches like this:

```
string search = "paul";

search = search.ToUpper();
var people = db.People
    .Where(p => p.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(search)
    .Where(p => p.MiddleName.ToUpper().Contains(search)
    .Where(p => p.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(search);
```

This works great. But then, if the user search for, by example:

```
search = "Henry Gates";
```

Oops.. in theory, this **(1)** must work:

```
    .Where(p => (p.FirstName +" "+ p.MiddleName +" "+ p.LastName).ToUpper().Contains(search);
```

Or this **(2)** must work:

```
    .Where(p => (p.FirstName.ToUpper() +" "+ p.MiddleName.ToUpper() +" "+ p.LastName.ToUpper()).Contains(search);
```

and there are an option **(3)** I can think:

```
.Select(p => new {FullName = p.FirstName +" "+ p.MiddleName +" "+ p.LastName)} )
.Where(p => p.FullName.Contains(search) )
```

Finally, my question. In little tables, this is not so relevant, but in big tables (like 500k records), it can be a problem because (in my example) FirstName, MiddleName and LastName are indexed fields, and searching in each field separately is fine, but concatenating the fields on queries, the SQL will do full table scans instead of use indexes, turning a simple query painful slow.

Using EntityFramework/Linq is yet more complex, because I dont know exactly what the criteria that will be used to concatenate my fields.

**Then what the recomended way to search in concatenated columns?**

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just curious, does "Henry Gates" must be equal to "MiddleName + LastName"? or it can be "MiddleName = Henry Gates"? or it can be "MiddleName = Gates, LastName = Henry", which means position is not relevant? if yes, then maybe convert the "Henry Gates" to array, and `Where(p => searchArray.Contains(p.FirstName) || ... || ...)`

Comment: @Prisoner equals to  "MiddleName + LastName". but position is not relevant, but not required... if find "Gates Henry" I can see as bonus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the position is not relevant, you can break the input string into `List` first, and use `contains` to find the match result

```
// Define the search string
List<string> searchInput = new List<string> { "Paul", "Henry Gates", "Gates Henry" };

// Define the data
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "William", MiddleName = "Henry", LastName = "Gates" });
persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Steven", MiddleName = "Paul", LastName = "Jobs" });
persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Mark", MiddleName = "Elliot", LastName = "Zuckerberg" });

// It may problem if you want to specific the field in sequence
persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Henry", MiddleName = "Elliot", LastName = "Gates" });
// Another problem if a field contains all values
persons.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Henry Gates", MiddleName = "Elliot", LastName = "Gates" });

// find the person
foreach (string input in searchInput)
{
    List<string> inputList = input.Split(' ').Select(s => s.ToUpperInvariant()).ToList();
    var qry = persons.Where(p => inputList.Contains(p.FirstName.ToUpperInvariant()) ||
                                    inputList.Contains(p.MiddleName.ToUpperInvariant()) ||
                                    inputList.Contains(p.LastName.ToUpperInvariant()));
    var results = qry.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Search: {0} Found: {1}", input, results.Count));
    foreach(var p in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Here is the result:

```
Search: Paul Found: 1
First Name: Steven; Middle Name: Paul; Last Name: Jobs

Search: Henry Gates Found: 3
First Name: William; Middle Name: Henry; Last Name: Gates
First Name: Henry; Middle Name: Elliot; Last Name: Gates
First Name: Henry Gates; Middle Name: Elliot; Last Name: Gates

Search: Gates Henry Found: 3
First Name: William; Middle Name: Henry; Last Name: Gates
First Name: Henry; Middle Name: Elliot; Last Name: Gates
First Name: Henry Gates; Middle Name: Elliot; Last Name: Gates
```

Hope this can fit your purpose

Fiddle: http://rextester.com/XFXBEQ27713